# Formulário para cadastro de equipamento com sequencia de numeros de lote

Tags: php, mysqli

alguem poderia me ajudar nesse problema. segue o codigo:

```
<?php
    $equipamento = $_POST['equipamento'];
    $departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
    $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
    $NInicial = $_POST['NInicial'];
    $NFinal =$_POST['NFinal'];
    $data=date('Y-m-d ');
    $valores = range( $NInicial, $NFinal );
    $sql = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO equipamentos(numero) VALUES (%s)', implode( '), (' , $valores ) );

    // CASO ESTEJA TUDO OK ADICIONA OS DADOS, SENÃO MOSTRA O ERRO
    if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
    // MOSTRA A MENSAGEM DE SUCESSO
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Cada cadeira tem um número, quero por exemplo cadastrar as cadeiras do numero 50 a 69 no departamento tal. Com isso no banco vai gerar 20 registros com essa sequencia de números com o nome do equipamento e departamento. O problema é que não sei adaptar os outros campos junto ao número sequencial. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

A função range retorna para a variável `$valores` um array. Logo poderá ser feito o seguinte:

```
//códido omitido
$valores = range( $NInicial, $NFinal );

foreach($valores as $key => $valor){
    $valores[$key] .= ', "'.$equipamento.'", "'.$departamento.'"';
}

$sql = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO equipamentos(numero) VALUES (%s)', implode( '), (' , $valores ) );
```

Caso os valores fossem:

```
1.NInicial:50
2.NFinal:69
3.equipamento:Motoserra
4.departamento:construção
5.observacao:Nada a declarar
```

Isso gerará a seguinte String de insert:

```
INSERT INTO equipamentos(numero) VALUES (50, "Motoserra", "construção"), (51, "Motoserra", "construção"), (52, "Motoserra", "construção"), (53, "Motoserra", "construção"), (54, "Motoserra", "construção"), (55, "Motoserra", "construção"), (56, "Motoserra", "construção"), (57, "Motoserra", "construção"), (58, "Motoserra", "construção"), (59, "Motoserra", "construção"), (60, "Motoserra", "construção"), (61, "Motoserra", "construção"), (62, "Motoserra", "construção"), (63, "Motoserra", "construção"), (64, "Motoserra", "construção"), (65, "Motoserra", "construção"), (66, "Motoserra", "construção"), (67, "Motoserra", "construção"), (68, "Motoserra", "construção"), (69, "Motoserra", "construção")
```

Abs